# NDK shared library "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I created very simple shared library and built it using NDK so that I wanna use it in a native android project, this library has a class called shaderprogram and its header file, I build it with this mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeGLLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NativeGLLib.cpp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes
APP_ABI:=all

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

then I copy the includes folder manually to the native project jni folder and copy the libs content from the library build to jni/lib, it is contains versions for devices arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a and so on.
I have a class called game.cpp where I implement the shared library

```
#include "includes/game.h"

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

#include "includes/shaderprogram.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace GameEngine::Core;

ShaderProgram shaderP;
int programId;

void on_surface_created() {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    programId = shaderP.getProgramId();
}

void on_surface_changed() {
    // No-op
}

void on_draw_frame() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

this is the android.mk file for the project

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(APP_ABI)/libNativeGLLib.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := game
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := glnative.cpp game.cpp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mylib

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

when I try build the project I get this error

```
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libgame.so
 ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libNativeGLLib.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libgame.so] Error 1

Comment: Uh.. shouldn't you be using `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` instead of `APP_ABI` in your second `Android.mk`?

Comment: It is worked, thank you